# Convert Asyncronus reset into syncronus reset in verilog

Tags: linux, shell

I have multiple Verilog RTL files in which we have use asynchronous reset. But I want to convert asyncronus reset to synchronous reset.

Before:

```
always @ (posedge clock or negedge reset)
```

After:

```
always @ (posedge clock)
```

or:

```
always @ (posedge clock) // or negedge reset)
```

By manually it takes more time.  So how can I do by script?

Answer (score 0):

Just use sed.

```
sed -i -re 's,(always @ \(posedge clock) [^)]*,\1,' source.v
```

or,

```
sed -i -re 's,(always @ \(posedge clock) ,\1) //,' source.v
```